# Global variable during ajax calls not updating properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

So Javascript is not multithreaded. But I have the following problem. 
I use AJAX calls from a function called from `setTimeout`. I need to know be able to distinguish when there are active AJAX calls before rescheduling the function.
For that I am using 2 global variables. So the code structure is as follows:

```
setTimeout(some_function, 10000);     
window.ajax_running = 0;  
window.calls_so_far = 0;  
function some_function () {  
   if(window.ajax_running) {  
     setTimeout(some_function, 10000);    
     return;  
   }  
   window.ajax_running = 1;  
   $.ajax({  
   //various  
  success: function (data) {   
         window.calls_so_far = window.calls_so_far + 1;     
         console.log('Running calls: '  + window.calls_so_far);  
         if(window.calls_so_far >=  SOME_VALUE) {  
              //we are ok ajax has finished  
              window.ajax_running = 0;  
         }  
}
```

Simple code. The problem is that it does not work. I see in the console:

Running calls: 1
So the global variable is not being incremented. It is as is each AJAX call sees the original value 0 and increments it (like as if there were threads).
What am I messing up here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you initialised your window.calls_so_far somewhere? something like window.calls_so_far = 0

Comment: @StefanoOrtisi:Yes they are set to 0

Comment: window.ajax_running = 0; once the ajax is finished

Comment: I have many ajax calls running

Comment: You should close the console.log function with an `)`. And you can replace your increment line with `window.calls_so_far += 1;`

Comment: At what point are you setting `window.ajax_running` back to 0? In the `success` callback?

Comment: @BillF:I reset it in `if(window.ajax_running >=  SOME_VALUE)` but I never go in this if.See update

Answer (score 0):

When success runs, the ajax call had already finished, so you are not running this call when u add calls_so_far. 
I'm not sure why u need the call to be "counted", but if is just the other problem (to call the same function after the first had finished, i would suggest this approach:

```
var counter;
counter = 0;

function recallSomeFunction() {
    setTimeout(some_function, 10000);     
}

function some_function () {        
 $.ajax({  
 //various  
 success: function (data) {   
     if (++counter < SOME_VAL) recallSomeFunction();
     //...
 },
 error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )) {   
     recallSomeFunction()
     //...
 });
 }
```

Comment: I am incrementing the counter to see how many ajax calls have finished. When they have *all* finished (if condition) I mark the ajax as not running. See updated OP

Comment: So I added a counter variable. This should work. The way of dealing with asynchronous calls without Semaphores is always securer (more secure?? not a great english speaker) ;-)

Comment: But I also use a counter.  Changing from `window.` to just `var` does not work either. Same issue